# using a variable name inside another variable name

Tags: php, forms, request

I'm sorry for my English.

1. I have a dynamic php form connected to mysql DB. In stock array I save the mysql query results. I can access the name of the product[0] and its available quantity [4]. I use the name of the product[0] to set input name and available quantity to fix max parameter value, as it below:

```html
 <input type="number" name="<?php echo $stock[$i][0]?>" min="0" max="<?php echo $stock[$i][4]; ?>" value="0" style="width:4em>
```

2. I don't kwow how many inputs will be created (and which, because it is dynamic), so I save the name of the input created in another array $_SESSION["INPUTS"] as show:

```php
    array_push($_SESSION["inputs"],$stock[$i][0]);
```

3. In the next page, I want to $REQUEST the value from the inputs. Now I have the problem, I need to call $REQUEST for the created inputs which names are saved inside $_SESSION["inputs"], I need something as:` $REQUEST["$_SESSION["inputs"]]. I try it different ways without exit.
   Any idea? Any alternative?

thanks

Comment: why use $_REQUEST? when you can access session in any pages ?

Comment: why do you say you  need to call `$REQUEST` for the created inputs which names are saved inside `$_SESSION["inputs"]`? Sidenote, `$_REQUEST` (with underscore) is an associative array that by default contains the contents of $_GET, $_POST and $_COOKIE.

Comment: unbalanced backtick, double quote in this ` $REQUEST["$_SESSION["inputs"]]

Comment: Hi man, don't be sorry for your English, most of people here are not native. You can use https://www.grammarly.com/ to check you grammar before posting (and you'll be learning what mistakes you're doing at the same time)

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is by naming the input `name` attribute like an array: eg: "name=stock[**the product name**]". This approach allows you to discard the usage of the `$_SESSION["inputs"]`.

```
<input type="number" name="stock[<?php echo $stock[$i][0];?>]" min="0" max="<?php echo $stock[$i][4]; ?>" value="0" style="width:4em">
```

Then to read the values:

```
$stocks = $_REQUEST['stock'];
foreach($stocks as $productName => $quantity) {
    //...
}
```

This works because the inputs are converted to a php array after being submitted.

You can even get the number of inputs by calling `count`:

```
echo count($_REQUEST['stock']);
```